# php count files from multiple folders and echo total

Tags: php, directory

I have a php code that will display the amount of files that i have in a folder.

**Code:** This will echo this on my page, "**There are a total of 119 Articles**"

```
$directory = "../health/";
if (glob($directory . "*.php") != false) /* change php to the file you require either html php jpg png. */ {
    $filecount = count(glob($directory . "*.php")); /* change php to the file you require either html php jpg png. */
    echo "<p>There are a total of";
    echo " $filecount ";
    echo "Articles</p>";
} else {
    echo 0;
}
```

**Question:**

I am wanting to count the files from 27 or more folders and echo the total amount of files.

Is there away i can add a list of folders to open such as:

```
$directory = "../health/","../food/","../sport/";
```

then it will count all the files and display the total **"There are a total of 394 Articles"**

Thanks

Comment: What exactly prevents you to count the files from those three directories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can:

```
glob('../{health,food,sport}/*.php', GLOB_BRACE);
```

Comment: Where should this be placed within the code? i have tried all sorts but it seems to only display the total from health folder. the other two guys have working solutions but they said yours is better also hakre's method works also. sorry to be a pain.[link]http://test.whatanswered.com/health/what-can-a-first-aider-do.php

Comment: `$filecount = count(glob('../{health,food,sport}/*.php', GLOB_BRACE));` will return the count of *.php files from 3 directories.

Comment: thanks i tried that before but i must have done something wrong as its working now, many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Undoubtedly, this is less efficient than [clover](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1982115/clover)'s answer:

```
$count = 0;
$dirs = array("../health/","../food/","../sport/");
foreach($dirs as $dir){
    if($files = glob($dir."*.php")){
        $count += count($files);
    }
}

echo "There are a total of $count Articles";
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple answer is to just use an array and a loop. It is something you could have figured out yourself.

```
$directories = array('../health/', '../food/', '../sport/');
$count = 0;
foreach ($directories as $dir) {
    $files = glob("{$dir}*.php") ?: array();
    $count += count($files);
}
echo "<p>There are a total of {$count} articles</p>";
```

But @clover's answer is better.

Answer (score 1):

As usual, it's often much better to divide your problem. E.g.:

- Obtain the files (See [`glob`](http://php.net/glob)).
- Count the files of a `glob` result (Write a function that takes care of two the `FALSE` and `Array` cases.).
- Do the output (don't do the output inside the other code, do it at the end, use variables (as you already do, just separate the output)).

Some Example Code:

```
/**
 * @param array|FALSE $mixed
 * @return int
 * @throws InvalidArgumentException
 */
function array_count($mixed) {

    if (false === $mixed) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (!is_array($mixed)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('Parameter must be FALSE or an array.');
    }

    return count($mixed);
}

$directories = array("health", "food", "string");
$pattern     = sprintf('../{%s}/*.php', implode(',', $directories));
$files       = glob($pattern, GLOB_BRACE);
$filecount   = array_count($files);

echo "<p>There are a total of ", $filecount, " Article(s)</p>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the opendir command explained here: 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php

combined with the example shown on previous link:

```
<?php
$dir = "/etc/php5/";

// Open a known directory, and proceed to read its contents
if (is_dir($dir)) {
    if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
        while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
            echo "filename: $file : filetype: " . filetype($dir . $file) . "\n";
        }
        closedir($dh);
    }
}
?>
```

Basically opening the folder you first go through and in a loop count every singel item that is not a folder.

**Edit:**
Seems like someone has given a simpler solution than this.